# Convert eval() to JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, json, eval, xss, code-injection

I was going through the ill-effects of using eval() with respect to XSS based attacks. There is a piece of code which I need to protect against a possible XSS attack, and what I guess that JSON.parse() should work fine.

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
var url = encDataPath + "/jcr:content/metadata.json?_charset_=utf-8";
url = Granite.HTTP.externalize(url);
request.open("GET", url ,false);
request.send(null);

var jsonData =eval("(" + request.responseText + ")"); // <-- here
var assetTitle = jsonData["dc:title"];
var mimetype = jsonData["dc:format"];
```

Can someone advise how can I change the `eval()` (for jsonData) to JSON.parse?

Comment: This question seems to answer itself...?

Comment: I don't understand why do you ask how to replace one thing with another when it's seem almost too obvious and the answer below. And why is it tagged under [xss] and [code-injection]? Wierd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just replace that line with:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Provided the response is proper JSON, this should just work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the response is well-behaved JSON, you would be able to simply replace the eval line with:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
```

Beware though: the JSON parser is very restrictive in the values that it will accept, compared to the Javascript objects that eval would accept. For instance,

```
var jsVal = eval("({a:3})");
```

will result in the Object {a: 3}, whereas

```
var jsonVal = JSON.parse("{a:3}");
```

will result in a parse error because the JSON specification[0] requires object keys to be provided as double-quoted strings:

```
var jsonVal = JSON.parse('{"a":3}');
```

If the server is properly configured it will generally output compliant JSON but it is something to be aware of.

[0] http://www.json.org/

Comment: Look at the url: `/jcr:content/metadata.json`. I think it's a pretty safe bet the response is valid JSON.